Definition of heap used by std::is_heap and std::make_heap
According to this page, there a two definitions of a heap (used by std::make_heap, std::is_heap, etc..) :
Until C++20 :

A random access range [first, last) is a heap with respect to a
comparator comp if bool(comp(first[(i - 1) / 2], first[i])) is false
for all integer i in (​0​, last - first).

Since C++20 :

A random access range [first, last) is a heap with respect to a comparator comp if the range is a heap with respect to comp and
std::identity{} (the identity projection).

Do you have a simpler definition? For example, when comp is std::less ? I don't understand the usage.

"in (0, last - first)" is an exclusive range - neither 0 nor last - first are parts of it. They borrowed common math notation - you can see [first, last) range in the same sentence, which includes first but not last. Square brackets mean "including", parens mean "excluding", and they can be matched in any combination. For a more detailed definition, see Wiki.

ok thanks a lot, i will edit the question to remove the note about the error and let a request for a clearer defintion.

I finally found the answer on wikipedia, a heap is :

a tree stocked in an array,
where the parent of element i is at index (i-1)/2
every parent is greater than or equal to its child for a max heap (resp. lower for a min heap).

